# include new line in HTML button

Tags: html, markdown

Having textareas with markdown formatting is appealing to me but not everybody is as positive as I am.

Using the HTML buttons could perhaps make the experience a bit more gentle. Editing the H1-6 buttons seemed to be a no-brainer at first. But if I could figure out how to have those buttons append a new line to the headings I would have to handle a lot less complaints about how stupid Markdown is when Wordpress has wysiwyg-editors like Word...

So. Is there a way to achieve a new line with the HTML-buttons?

/David

Answer (score 1):

The HTML button setting fields won't let you pass a line break to the textarea field, so there's no direct way to do it via the button. You may need to look into an alternative markdown fieldtype add-on.

Comment: Ok, Thats what I feared. Is there a md-addon that stands out in your opinion?

Comment: For your clients, I'd try Markdown Field: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/markdown-field